# What is the regular expression to extract 123+43 from the String 'What is (123+43)?' in the regular expression extractor of JMeter?

Tags: java, javascript, testing, jmeter

The actual html response contains large data among which the following piece of line comes in between

```
<span style="width:50%"><font color="#000000">What is (123+43)?</font></span>
```

The numbers within the braces vary each time and also the arithmetic operand. So How can I  get the whole string within the braces using regex extractor in JMeter?

I used What is /(([^)]+))/ but I am not getting anything.

Also I would like to know how to perform the arithmetic operation in JMeter after extracting the String and assign it to a variable. I tried using JSR233 preprocessor, but I don't know how to send back the result to the next Http Request.

PS: The closest I could achieve for extracting the expression from "**What is (123+43)?**" is `What is (.+?\))` But it gives output as (123+43). I want to remove the braces as well. That is were I am struck.

The place I added regex

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtugV.png

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with Java?

Comment: I used Javascript language in JSR233. I thought of using engine.eval(given_Input_String_Arithmetic_Expression).

Comment: Do you have to use a regex? Why not use indexOf("(") and lastIndexOf(")") to get the position of the brackets and then extract what's in between them with substring()?

Comment: Nope. First I need to get the values in between braces from the whole HTML response and only then I can proceed to perform the operation.

Comment: This maybe `\d[^)]+`?

Comment: Nope doesn't work. The tricky part is we need to exclude the braces that comes in the question, but we will be using ( ) as part of regex. When I did some research JMEter uses Perl5 type of regex. But tried for 6+ hours with various combinations and couldn't get the results.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "doesn't work". `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d[^)]+").matcher("What is (123+43)?"); m.find(); System.out.println(m.group());` prints `123+43`. Is it not what you wanted?

Comment: Dude. See here "Note: unlike Perl, there is no need to (i.e. do not) enclose the regular expression in //." Source : http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html  in the very first paragraph.

Comment: Who are you talking to? Dude ...

Comment: Oh Sorry. I am new to Stackoverflow. I was replying to you. By the way, doesm't work I mean is I am not getting 123+43.

Comment: Do you need to be able to handle parentheses inside?  Like `"What  is (500-(123+43))?"`

Comment: @user3705801 I don't know why you are replying to me with that quote. I have never suggested that you enclose anything into //. The regex I gave you - `\d[^)]+` -  does work. If you are not "getting 123+43", you are "getting" it wrong. Impossible to tell more without knowing what exactly you are doing. Show your code.

Comment: @DavidWallace Nope. My requirement is just two numbers inside the braces and the arithmetic operator will be either + or -.

Comment: Could the first number be negative?  Like `"What is (-123+43)?"`  If not, then Dima's solution works perfectly.

Comment: @DavidWallace good point about negative numbers :) `-?\d[^)]+`

Comment: @Dima There won't be negative numbers as first operand. I have added the code and Jmeter screenshot.

Comment: @user3705801 there are junk words "What is" in the regular expression field in your screenshot. That's why it does not work. Remove them, put in the exact expression I have given you. No initiative :) I don't know what this tool you are using expects, you might need to include it into parethesis, like this: `(-?\d[^)])`

Comment: @Dima I get null when I do that. I guess we need to add "What is", because when I use What is (.+?\)), it works , but I get along with braces.The response html data is very big but the word "What is" comes only once in the page.

Comment: So ...  you're saying you want to match that whole sentence out of a larger piece of text, then just return the part in the parentheses?  That is an ENTIRELY different question.  Incidentally, the answer involves lookaheads and lookbehinds.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yep. Sorry about that. Could you help me please.

Answer (score 1):

For finding both no. seperately you can use below expression,

```
What is \((\d+)(.)(\d+)\)\?
```

Template value in JMeter Regex extractor will be `$1$$2$$3$`

If your extractor ref name is val then

```
val_g1 will be 123
val_g2 will be +
val_g3 will be 43
```

For addition of 2 nos. you can use beanshell preprocessor in JMeter.
Provide extracted values along with operator to a beanshell processor and perform arithmetic operations on it and pass on the result variable to next request.

examples are here, [JMeter Advance features.](http://training-course-material.com/training/JMeter_Advanced)

Comment: But the arithmertic operator varies randomly. Some time it will be addition, some time it will subtraction.

Comment: Beanshell preprocessor is a simple java code. all arithmetic operations can be done using it. But if you are saying that operator can vary then you need operator too. see updated regex and answer.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't say anything about arithmetic operations.

Comment: Link gives overview of Beanshell processor. how to use beanshell processor and how to pass values in and out. you can't expect whole code of beanshell processor here. These are just pointers. you should figure out solution on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you want is

```
(?<=What is \()[-+\d]+(?=\)\?)
```

Don't forget to escape the backslashes, something like `"(?<=What is \\()[-+\\d]+(?=\\)\\?)"`, if you're using it as a Java `String` literal or similar.

This uses a positive lookbehind, between `(?<=` and `)`, followed by the part you want to match, followed by a positive lookahead, between `(?=` and `)`.  For the part you want to match, I've assumed that any string of digits, pluses and minuses is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
What is \((.+?)\)\?
```

Hope is helps.

Comment: Works like a charm. Could you answer the other part, like how to solve the string in JMeter? Thanks

Comment: I thought you only wanted to match the part in parentheses, not the whole sentence?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with JMeter. I looked into the document that might be helpful: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval.